# How to convert a NUMERIC field into a DATE field and use it in a WHERE clause in DB2?

Tags: sql, date, casting, db2

I have a field that is integer format `20220801` that needs to be converted to a date field. I then need to use this field in a WHERE clause compared against the `CURRENT DATE`. This is specifically for DB2.

Every time I try to do this I receive this error message:

[image: DB2 Error Message]

Here are some snippets I've tried unsuccessfully, each time returning the above error

```
SELECT
    DATE(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(CHAR(BWDUED), 'YYYYMMDD')) AS DUE_DATE,
    CURRENT DATE AS TODAY_DATE
FROM
    SCHEMA.TABLE
WHERE
    DATE(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(CHAR(BWDUED), 'YYYYMMDD')) = CURRENT_DATE
```

```
SELECT
    DATE(TO_DATE(CHAR(BWDUED), 'YYYYMMDD')) AS DUE_DATE,
    CURRENT DATE AS TODAY_DATE
FROM
    SCHEMA.TABLE
WHERE
    DATE(TO_DATE(CHAR(BWDUED), 'YYYYMMDD')) = CURRENT_DATE
```

I've looked at many of the answers on here, but none of them have gotten me past this error. Any help on navigating this would be appreciated!

Comment: what does CHAR(BWDUED) return?  The error seems to imply it isn't 8 characters.  You will likely get better performance converting CURRENT_DATE to the proper integer format.

Comment: It returns the original 8 digits now as string.

What is the right way to go about converting CURRENT_DATE?

Comment: If you stored dates as dates, this wouldn't be a problem. Make your life (and ours) easier and use the proper types.

Comment: Well, that's not really up to me. Trust me, I wish these were stored as dates from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [TIMESTAMP_FORMAT](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=functions-timestamp-format). It allows to specify the input format and you get a TIMESTAMP or DATE back.

```
VALUES (TIMESTAMP_FORMAT('20220801','YYYYMMDD'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because some row contains a number which can't be formatted as a timestamp with the specified pattern.

Consider the following example returning exactly the same error, if you uncomment any of the commented out lines.

```
SELECT
    DATE (TIMESTAMP_FORMAT (CHAR(BWDUED), 'YYYYMMDD')) AS DUE_DATE,
    CURRENT DATE AS TODAY_DATE
FROM
    (
    VALUES 
      --0 ,
      --20221232, 
      INT (TO_CHAR (CURRENT DATE, 'YYYYMMDD'))
    ) T (BWDUED)
WHERE
    DATE (TIMESTAMP_FORMAT (CHAR(BWDUED), 'YYYYMMDD')) = CURRENT_DATE
```

The solution would be create a "safe" formatter function eating possible errors, and use it instead of `TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` (or synonym `TO_DATE` function).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TO_DATE_SAFE 
(
  P_STR VARCHAR (128)
, P_FMT VARCHAR (128)  
)
RETURNS TIMESTAMP
CONTAINS SQL
NO EXTERNAL ACTION
DETERMINISTIC 
BEGIN 
  DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
  BEGIN 
    RETURN CAST (NULL AS TIMESTAMP);
  END;
  RETURN TO_DATE (P_STR, P_FMT);
END
```

Comment: This just helped me realize the problem! There is a 0 in the column that is throwing this whole thing off. I think the easiest way to go about this is to do what @Scott Mildenberger suggested and turn the CURRENT_DATE into an integer instead of trying to turn BWDUED into a date

Comment: Yes, it would be better solution, since it's hard to believe, that db2 would try to evaluate expressions specified in the SELECT list on unfiltered rows. So, you shouldn't get the same error...

Comment: Converting current_date to an int is better from a performance standpoint also.  Especially if there are indexes over BWDUED

Comment: Alan Campin has published a set of UDF's for just this purpose: http://www.think400.dk/downloads.htm